# Keras IMDB dataset 0 vs ovv_char

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am looking at the documentation for the [Keras preprocessed IMDB dataset](https://keras.io/datasets/#imdb-movie-reviews-sentiment-classification), which says:

> As a convention, "0" does not stand for a specific word, but instead is used to encode any unknown word.

However, I am not seeing "0" in the data when I try:

```
(inputTrain, yTrain), (inputTest, yTest) = imdb.load_data(num_words=vocabSize)
```

Am I missing something? I also don't see "0" being added in the preprocessing code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/imdb.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a convention, "0" does not stand for a specific word, but instead is used to encode any unknown word.

The documentation is wrong here. In Keras IMDB dataset, the value:

- "0" stands for padding (i.e. to make all the sequences have the same lengths as needed),
- "1" stands for start token, i.e. denoting the start of a document,
- "2" stands for OOV (Out-Of-Vocabulary) token, i.e. representing all the tokens which are not in the dictionary or, as used in the documentation, *unknown word*.

So, in Keras IMDB dataset, "2" is used for unknown words, and not "0".

Comment: Thanks today for the edits and the answer. Hmm, I don't see "0" in the loaded data at all; is Keras's `load_data` really doing any padding?

Comment: @rishai No, the data has not been padded. Because that's something the end user decides to do it or not depending on the task/approach.